# Centralised logging configuration when sharing libraries between packages

Tags: logging, go, scope, package

So I'm using a structured logging library ([logrus](https://github.com/Sirupsen/)), and I have a `core` package used as a base for some other packages, lets call this package `me/core`, then individual packages like `me/foo-service`, `me/bar-service` etc. that use this core library for common dependencies/utilities such as setup, configuration loading, and I also wanted to use it for standardized things like logging, so I want `me/core` to be able to configure logging for the other packages, with Logrus you can do things like

```
import(
  log "github.com/Sirupsen/logrus"
)
[...]
log.SetLevel(log.DebugLevel)
log.SetFormatter(&log.TextFormatter{FullTimestamp:true})
```

Then do;

```
log.Debug("Moo")
log.WithFields(log.Fields{"structured":"data"}).Debug("I have structure data")
```

getting an output like

```
> DEBU[2016-04-12T22:11:38+01:00] Moo
> DEBU[2016-04-12T22:11:38+01:00] I have structure data           structured=data
```

So I want to configure this in my `me/foo-service` package with something like

```
import(
  "me/core/logging"
)

func main(){
  logging.Setup()
}
```

Only for various reasons I'm running into issues. The primary issue seems to be that both `me/core`, and `me/foo-service` have a vendored version of the `logrus` library, those `log.Set*` commands modify the variable `logrus.std` logger which holds the standard, global logger, but this is a seperate instance for both packages because `me/core/vendor/.../logrus/std` and `me/foo-service/vendor/.../logrus/std` are different objects.

First thing I tried was creating a variable in `me/core/logging` that I could use in the parent, so something like

```
package logging

import(
  log "github.com/Sirupsen/logrus"
)

var Log *log.Logger

func Setup(verbose bool){
  Log = log.New()
  if verbose{
    Log.Level = log.DebugLevel
  } else {
    Log.Level = log.InfoLevel
  }
  Log.Formatter = &log.TextFormatter{FullTimestamp:true}
  Log.Debug("Logging verbosely")
}
```

and that works for simple cases like this

```
package main

import(
  "me/core/logging"
)

func main() {
  logging.Setup(parsedOptions.Verbose)
  logging.Log.Debug("Moo")
}
```

However trying to use the structured data `Fields` causes problems, I can't use the local vendored `logrus` fields like

```
logging.Log.WithFields(log.Fields{"data":"hi"}).Debug("test")
```

as I get

```
cannot use "me/foo-service/vendor/github.com/Sirupsen/logrus".Fields literal (type "me/foo-service/vendor/github.com/Sirupsen/logrus".Fields) as type "me/core/vendor/github.com/Sirupsen/logrus".Fields in argument to logging.Log.WithFields
```

And trying to mirror the field in `me/core/logging` with something like

```
type Fields log.Fields
```

Doesn't work ether because it's still a different type

```
cannot use logging.Fields literal (type logging.Fields) as type "me/core/vendor/github.com/Sirupsen/logrus".Fields in argument to logging.Log.WithFields
```

I also can't think of any way to pass my local `log.std` from `me/foo-service` to `me/core` as it's also a different type due to the vendored package.

My work around for the moment involves creating a mirror of every method, so in `me/core/logging` I have a set up like

```
package logging

import(
  log "github.com/Sirupsen/logrus"
)

var Log *log.Logger
type Fields map[string]interface{}

func Setup(verbose bool){
  Log = log.New()
  if verbose{
    Log.Level = log.DebugLevel
  } else {
    Log.Level = log.InfoLevel
  }
  Log.Formatter = &log.TextFormatter{FullTimestamp:true}
  Log.Debug("Logging verbosely")
}

func Debug(msg interface{}){
  Log.Debug(msg)
}

func WithFields(fields Fields) *log.Entry{
  lf := log.Fields{}
  for k,v := range fields{
    lf[k] = v
  }
  return Log.WithFields(lf)
}
```

But that would involve creating a mirror for *every* method which seems really inefficient.

So I'd like a suggestion for how I can make `me/core/vendor/.../logrus/std` avaliable to `me/foo-service`, or if I'm thinking about this in completely the wrong way a better way to do it.

Comment: I think it's generally undesirable to have a library vendor it's own deps, specifically for reasons of version incompatibility and duplication.   The app (main package) should vendor everyone's deps and deal with conflicts if any.

Answer (score 1):

You can only mirror `WithFields` since the other ones accept built in types. Also since `logging.Fields` and `logrus.Fields` are the same type you could more simply do

```
func WithFields(f Fields) log.*Entry {
    return Log.WithFields(log.Fields(f))
}
```

Then in your service, you could call

```
logging.Log.Debug("message")
logging.WithFields(logging.Fields{"k":"v"}).Debug("message")
```